# Difference between number of states and number of mixtures in Gaussian Mixture Model?

Tags: hidden-markov-models, hmmlearn, gaussian-mixture-model

I am using the GMMHMM library and I can not figure out the difference between

```
 n_components : Number of states in the model.
 n_mix : Number of states in the GMM.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

n_components means the states in the Hidden Markov Model; n_mix means the number of the mixtures in the mixture gaussian distribution corresponding to each state.